# Finding Where Previous Email In Conversation Is Stored in a Shared Inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

When receiving a reply to an email that has already been in a shared inbox, I want to store it to the same folder as the previous email.

Came as far as understanding Conversation ID buildup, but couldn't find how to read the properties of the previous conversation.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides the [GetConversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getconversation) method which obtains a `Conversation` object that represents the conversation to which this item belongs. GetConversation returns Null (Nothing in Visual Basic) if no conversation exists for the item. No conversation exists for an item in the following scenarios:

- The item has not been saved. An item can be saved programmatically, by user action, or by auto-save.
- For an item that can be sent (for example, a mail item, appointment item, or contact item), the item has not been sent.
- Conversations have been disabled through the Windows registry.
- The store does not support Conversation view (for example, Outlook is running in classic online mode against a version of Microsoft Exchange earlier than Microsoft Exchange Server 2010). Use the [IsConversationEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.isconversationenabled) property of the `Store` object to determine whether the store supports Conversation view.

I guess the `GetConversation` doesn't work for shared accounts , see [a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56750740/mailitem-getconversation-on-shared-mailbox) for more information.